# Knife Tool Limited Cut - Not Cutting All of Mesh/Edges

Tags: knife-tool

Currently, I am trying to cut my mesh in half with the knife tool, *K*. The cutting seems to work at the top and side of the mesh (I pressed enter), but it won't apply at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Img1 and Img2 show the bottom edges which I am not able to cut**. The knife tool won't even apply on these edges and doesn't change them into the red/purple color.

**Img3 shows the cuts at the top and side which work perfectly fine.** Without the bottom, I am not able to cut my mesh in half. Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In future please crop your images to only the relevant areas and upload them directly to your question instead of linking to them.

Comment: It's hard to make out what's happening in the images but have you checked your model for doubles? Go to edit mode, hit Atrl-A, then W - Remove Doubles.

Comment: Try uploading a .blend file. Maybe also consider using _Ctrl + R_ for Loop Cut instead of the knife tool (more efficient/easier).

Comment: @ Ray - Hi, sorry... in future i'll do that, thank you ! ...... @ metaphor - My bad , you were right !!! after i used "remove doubles" it worked. Thank you so much !! ..... @ Shady - i'll keep that in mind. i like the loop cut function ! .... thank you all for your help

Comment: @Roadhouseman If you want to mention a user you need to make sure there is no space between '@' and their username, otherwise they won't be notified.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said "trying to cut my mesh in half ", is using the knife tool mandatory? Maybe you already discarded them, but there are other (probably better) tools, like the bisect tool, or the boolean modifier.

Bisect tool: this allows you to create edges through the whole mesh by setting a "bisect" line, like this:

1. Start switching the 3D view in edit mode, and adjust view to allow you to "bisect" drawing on the 3D view, like:

[image]

2. After clicking on "bisect", draw a single line (eg) from top to bottom: after confirming the end point, the cut is already done!

[image]

3. Now your mesh has an edge that goes through all its geometry: you can use this dividing line as reference to delete all geometry (eg) to the right of it:

[image]

you'll get

[image]

Another way, as said, it using boolean difference, and since is a modifier, is also non-destructive (until you apply):

1. Create a big cube that contains all the part of the mesh that should be "cut" away from the mesh

[image]

2. Then select your mesh, and apply a "difference" boolean, with the big cube as target

[image]

3. Done! Your mesh is cut, but you can still change cube (and this cut) position. Note that the cut zone ill be "closed" by a side - you can get rid of this after, if needed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the knife tool can do what he wants, exactly the same way the bisect tool does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're missing something.

The Knife Tool can cut all the way through a mesh if you toggle "cut through" by pressing <kbd>z</kbd>. Notice at the bottom of the 3D Viewport after you press <kbd>k</kbd> to start the Knife Tool, there are instructions about the other functions the Knife Tool can use. It'll even show you whether "Cut through" is currently ON or OFF.

It also describes other functions of the Knife Tool that you might find useful.